# Not overwriting *standard-input* prevents multi-threading

Tags: multithreading, lisp, common-lisp, ecl

I have a Common Lisp program that behaves differently depending on how  I use `*standard-input*`. Here are the details:

```
(if input-stream?
    (process)
    (with-open-file (*standard-input* up :element-type 'unsigned-byte)
      (process)))
```

The `process` function starts multiple threads. Each thread reads part of the **standard input**, writes it in a file (all within a lock) and processes the resulting files in parallel (out of the lock). In fact it processes the resulting files in parallel only in case `input-stream?` is `false` otherwise it processes them **sequentially**.

```
(defun process ()
  (let ((psize 4194304)
        (stream *standard-input*)
        (result-lock (bt:make-lock))
        (input-stream-lock (bt:make-lock))
        eof)
    (flet ((add-job (fname)
             (make-thread
              #'(lambda ()
                  (do () (eof)
                    (when (bt:with-lock-held (input-stream-lock)
                            (unless eof
                              (setq eof (write-input-stream-to-file stream fname psize))
                              t))
                      (sleep 0.1)
                      (bt:with-lock-held (result-lock)
                        (display-progress))))))))
      (mapcar
       #'join-thread
       (loop for i from 1 to 10
          collect (add-job
                   (make-pathname :directory "/tmp"
                                  :name "test" 
                                  :type (princ-to-string i))))))))

(let ((counter 0))
  (defun display-progress ()
    (if (zerop (mod (incf counter) 10))
        (format t " ~a " counter)
        (write-char #\+))))

(defun write-input-stream-to-file (stream fname psize-bytes)
  (with-open-file (out fname
                       :direction :output
                       :element-type 'unsigned-byte
                       :if-exists :supersede) 
    (do ((byte (read-byte stream nil nil)
               (read-byte stream nil nil))
         (offset 0 (1+ offset)))
        ((or (= offset psize-bytes) (null byte)) (not byte))
      (write-byte byte out))))
```

If we create a FIFO (with mkfifo), copy the file to it and run the program with it instead, we again observe parallelism.

The above program is built as a command line utility with ECL and runs on Linux. I run it in one of the following ways:

1. cat "bigfile" | my-program
2. my-program "bigfile"

Parallelism happens only in case 2.

The question is why the difference?

Update:

- I had mistake in my question. Now it is OK.
- Added the `process` function and described how I run the program

Comment: `*standard-input*` must be a text file, yours is binary. dunno if it matters in your case.

Comment: I think that you need to provide details on how you “run” this program, and what `process` does.

Comment: I tried with a text file and there was no difference. I just added requested details.

Comment: Why not distribute the input to files sequentially (because you're doing that anyway, just by locking) and then process the files in parallel?  Also: `read-sequence`!

Comment: @tfb Thanks for the suggested workaround. If I do this and my input file is X megabytes I will need 2*X the disk space needed to do the processing. I might don't have that much.

Comment: It won't double the space (although the worst case is always going to be that) if the algorithm is: 'read a chunk, spawn/find a worker for that chunk, read next chunk ...'.

Comment: @tfb I got your idea just now.  Do you think this would solve the problem with the standard input and make the operation parallel? I am not sure about that as I do not understand the root cause.

Comment: I don't know if it will fix it, but it will isolate the worker threads from any binding of special variables &/or mucking around with `*standard-input*`, which probably will help.